# How to change Rails 3 to_xml encoding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-2.1

Im using Rails 3 **to_xml** on a Model with a few options like include, except and methods.
So this is not my first time using **to_xml**.

I'm doing something like this:

```
to_xml(include: {
  order: {
    methods: [:my_avg],
    except:  [:this_attr, :and_this_attr ]
  },
  customer: {}
})
```

The XML result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<my-model>
  <attr1 type="integer">12</attr1>
  <attr2 type="integer">12</attr2>
  <order>
    <name>foo</name>
    <desc>bar</desc>
    <my-avg>
      <avg type="integer">123</avg>
      <foo>ok</foo>
    </my-avg>
  </order>
  <updated-at type="datetime">2014-04-14T11:16:56-03:00</updated-at>
</my-model>
```

But now I want to change the xml encoding ISO_8859_1 instead of utf8.

I haven't seen an encoding option on ActiveRecord::Serialization module.

If I simply add one encoding option it creates a XML attribute instead of changing the encoding that results on this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<my-model>
  <attr1 type="integer" encoding="ISO-8859-1">12</attr1>
  <attr2 type="integer" encoding="ISO-8859-1">12</attr2>
  <order>
    <name>foo</name>
    <desc>bar</desc>
    <my-avg>
      <avg type="integer">123</avg>
      <foo>ok</foo>
    </my-avg>
  </order>
  <updated-at type="datetime">2014-04-14T11:16:56-03:00</updated-at>
</my-model>
```

Is there a way to specify the encoding using ActiveRecord's to_xml?

Answer (score 0):

you may override `to_xml` in your Model & specify encoding. something like this could work:

```
class ModelName < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_xml(options = {})
    require 'builder'
    options[:indent] ||= 2
    xml = options[:builder] ||= ::Builder::XmlMarkup.new(indent: options[:indent])
    xml.instruct! :xml, :version=>"1.0", :encoding => "ISO-8859-1"
    xml.level_one do
      xml.tag!(:second_level, 'content')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It returns a rightfully encoded XML, but it did overwrite the default behavior. So the content is only: "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> <level_one <second_level>content</second_level>
</level_one>"

Comment: Yes, you have to implement that yourself. Because it seems rails by default doesn't allow you override encoding, so you have to monkey-patch or implement it yourself. to take some inspiration, [here is how rails does it](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activemodel/lib/active_model/serializers/xml.rb#L74-L97)